# Firebase 3.0 with typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to develop a web app with angular2 and firebase 3.0 authentication following the guidelines given by google. However all the guides for web have javascript examples.

I added below lines in my index.html

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
var config = {
   apiKey: "AIzaSyCSfBMvAdEDpcm-z6gWp2XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   authDomain: "fototrans-calculator.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://fototrans-calculator.firebaseio.com",
   storageBucket: "fototrans-calculator.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

But when i try to use

```
rootRef = firebase.database.ref();
```

I get an error on 'firebase' saying

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'firebase'.
```

Now I remember that I had installed firebase using typings for the previous version of Firebase. Do we have any such thing again for the new version of Firebase? Please guide.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

As of Firebase 3.2.1, the typings are included as part of the official NPM package:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#wzxhzdk4version_321_-_july_26_2016wzxhzdk5

Comment: I'm seeing tons of TypeScript compile errors when including these typings via `typings install --global --save file:...` and then compiling my project.

Comment: Does someone know of some working example code using these typings?

Comment: @ktusznio seems like the built-in typings only work with Typescript 2

Answer (score 4):

You can work around this by doing `declare var firebase: any;`

Comment: it works, but it does not benefit from Typescript typing any more

Comment: @Jacky I know :(  The new version of AngularFire2 has manual Firebase 3 typings but I haven't figured out how to get them working: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/manual_typings/firebase3/firebase3.d.ts

Comment: @Alex. Yeah, I'm having the same problems.
I'm trying to use firebase3 along with angularfire2 under the Angular CLI setup. While angularfire2 typings work well, I can't get the firebase3 ones to get recognized. Feel like I've tried all possible combinations.

Comment: @VitaliKniazeu I've decided to back up a bit and wait for it to mature a little, there's a been a lot of talk in the issue queue and I'm confident it'll be worked out soon!

Answer (score 4):

There is a type definition file available at https://github.com/suhdev/firebase-3-typescript

I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/suhdev/firebase-3-typescript/pull/1) that will hopefully solve the issue you are describing.

Comment: In your tsconfig.json file include the following line in your "files" array:

"files": [
  "node_modules/angularfire2/firebase3.d.ts"
]
This is a temporary step until the Firebase typings are published to npm.

Comment: FWIW, those typings blow up on tslint.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Typings definition file provided in the AngularFire2 GitHub repository (located [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/manual_typings/firebase3/firebase3.d.ts)):

Include the following in your `typings.json` file:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "firebase": "github:angular/angularfire2/manual_typings/firebase3/firebase3.d.ts#2c9ab3117eeb804e8e4996461eddcf32efa54a56"
  }
}
```

Note that the value here is simply the path to the file on GitHub followed by the relevant commit hash. The hash in the example is `master` at time of writing so you may wish to update to the latest commit.

Next you can run `node_modules/.bin/typings install` and Typings will apply the latest changes from your `typings.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use it this one:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/manual_typings/firebase3

And to get it to work you need to add it to your tsconfig.json:

```
"filesGlob": [
"**/*.ts",
"!node_modules/**/*",
"firebase3.d.ts"
],
```

And copy the file to the same folder as your tsconfig.json.